# What is the most efficient way of creating a sequence of timouts in JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

I receive a json object from server which looks something like that:

```
{1000: "Paragraph 1",
2000: "Paragraph 2",
2500: "Paragraph 3",
...
11500: "Paragraph 20",}
```

My task is to show these lines subsequently: the first one in 1 sec, the second in 2 seconds, the third in 2.5 seconds etc.

I can of course generate a series of `setTimeout`, but I wonder if there is more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: I wonder if this is a homework question that is showing us no existing effort at a solution.

Comment: No, you will need a series of timeouts.

Comment: Wonder if you can assign a setInterval to a var/let. Each interval, update the interval time for setInterval ... never tried that but would be interesting. You'd also need to test if all values have been handled then clearInterval()

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers so far pay heed to the OPs claim that he doesn't want to create multiple `setTimeout` or `setInterval`.

We really can create a single `setInterval` and get it to iterate through the JSON in intervals.

```
var data = {
  1000: "Paragraph 1",
  2000: "Paragraph 2",
  2500: "Paragraph 3",
  5000 : "Paragraph 5",
  11500: "Paragraph 20"
};

var keys = Object.keys(data);
var i = 0;

var handle = setInterval(()=> {

   console.log(data[keys[i++]]);

   if (i === keys.length)
     clearInterval(handle)

}, 250);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to show the lines using a consistent time difference between each you could use `setTimeout`'s brother function, `setInterval`.

If you want, you could use `setInterval` and use a function to change the interval time

```
var waitTime = 1000;
var myFunction = function(){
    //your code to display a line of text

    clearInterval(interval);
    waitTime += 50;  //make your changes to wait time
    interval = setInterval(myFunction, waitTime);
}
var interval = setInterval(myFunction, waitTime);
```

Lastly, you could use the jquery delay function, but this only works if you're using jquery effects to display the text. Read about it here: https://api.jquery.com/delay/

Ultimately, these are options that will work, but using `setTimeout` is the cleanest way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>While you tagged a Jquery</sup> .. So `$.each()` is a simple way to do that

<kbd>ES 5</kbd>

```js
var Json = {
  1000: "Paragraph 1",
  2000: "Paragraph 2",
  2500: "Paragraph 3",
  5000 : "Paragraph 5",
  11500: "Paragraph 20"
};


PrintResults(Json);


function PrintResults(result) {
  $.each(result , function(key , value){
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log('Time is: '+key+' .. Value is: '+value);
    } , key);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Additional** <kbd>ES 6</kbd>

```js
var Json = {
  1000: "Paragraph 1",
  2000: "Paragraph 2",
  2500: "Paragraph 3",
  5000 : "Paragraph 5",
  11500: "Paragraph 20"
};


PrintResults(Json);


function PrintResults(result) {
  $.each(result , (key , value) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`Time is: ${key} .. Value is: ${value}`);
    } , key);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using javascript like this

```js
var obj = {
    1000: "Paragraph 1",
    2000: "Paragraph 2",
    2500: "Paragraph 3",
    11500: "Paragraph 20"
}

function displayResults(obj){
    
    var time = Object.keys(obj);
    var val = Object.values(obj);
    time.forEach(function(item, index){
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log("The time is " + item + " The value is " + val[index]);
        }, item);
    }) 

}

displayResults(obj);
```

Comment: You are creating multiple `setTimeout`s in this approach.See my answer.

Comment: I understand. Thank you